# SQL Group Data within the date difference of 90 seconds

Tags: sql, excel, datetime

I have sample data like

| Element | Time Stamp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 21/12/2020 06:10:56 |
| B | 21/12/2020 06:05:27 |
| B | 21/12/2020 06:06:10 |
| A | 21/12/2020 06:11:27 |
| A | 21/12/2020 06:05:27 |
| A | 21/12/2020 06:06:20 |
| A | 21/12/2020 06:12:30 |

I need to write query either Excel or SQL to batch the above data in groups of date separated by 90 seconds
So, I should receive batches grouped by "Element" column with 90 seconds difference in TimeStamp.

Output

| Element | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 (21/12/2020 06:10:56 & 21/12/2020 06:11:27) 2 occurrences within 90 secs |
| A | 2 (21/12/2020 06:05:27 & 21/12/2020 06:06:20) 2 occurrences within 90 secs |
| A | 1 (21/12/2020 06:12:30) 1 occurrence (Note that 06:11:27 timestamp is already considered above) |
| B | 2 |

One row won't be counted again to make a batch.

I tried group by with Element using the dateDiff function but could not get the result. Any support will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want "islands" that are separated by 90 seconds.  If so, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum with aggregation:

```
select element, min(timestamp), max(timestamp), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_timestamp > dateadd(second, -90, timestamp) then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by element order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(timestamp) over (partition by element order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, element;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86ead5fd6d12b456ff4de1140e2c6bec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks very much for the query. When I ran it, it seems to give the same value for min(timestamp) & max(timestamp). I am learning how to modify it to my case where I have another column Element2 and want to batch my "islands" per Element1 per Element2. Anyway, thanks for the help. much appreciated.

Comment: @MeetMehta . . . This does not return the same values.  I added a db<>fiddle.  It doesn't return exactly what is in your question, though, so I may not have understood the question.

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear with my the question. Your solution would batch 3 rows together as<br/>

A 21/12/2020 06:10:56 <br/>
A 21/12/2020 06:11:27<br/>
A 21/12/2020 06:12:30<br/><br/>

first 2 rows have 90 sec difference but I and III row have more than 90 sec difference. So ideally I wanted first 2 rows together ( 90 sec difference ) <br / >
A 21/12/2020 06:10:56
A 21/12/2020 06:11:27 <br/>

and then third row as separate batch since the time slot between  06:10:56 & 06:10:56 (+90 seconds ) have only first 2 rows and III row as separate batch from after the time of 90 sec differenc.